# Spring integration asyc flow

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I have a requirement for my spring integration project where a status needs to be given when a user makes a restful call, for this call the server does some processing n calculates a status which should be retuned back, if the status is success then I need to make a call to 3rd party service but this is transparent to user (this 3rd party should be asynchronous) how can I achieve in spring integration

Answer (score 2):

I hope you use `<int-http:inbound-gateway>` for your REST service.

In this case you are expecting for the response in the `TemporaryReplyChannel`.

Typically reply transparently we should just use that channel from header.

All Spring Integration request-reply component do that when they aren't supplied with the `outputChannel`. That should really be felt organically: we don't have anything to do, so treat the absent of `outputChannel` as the end of flow. In case of `replyChannel` in headers we send our result back t othe caller. In your case into the HTTP Response.

Looks like that works for you already now.

To achieve your async requirements I'd suggests something like `PublishSubscribeChannel` with the `TaskExecutor` to be able to send the same message to several subscribers and do that in parallel manner.

The XML config on the matter may look like:

```
<service-activator input-channel="lastProcessChannel" output-channel="3rdPartyChannel"/>

<publish-subscribe-channel id="3rdPartyChannel" task-executor="taskExecutor"/>

<bridge input-channel="3rdPartyChannel"/>

<service-activator input-channel="3rdPartyChannel"/>
```

Independently of that `executor` the `<int-http:inbound-gateway>` will wait for the reply, so it won't hurt that our `async` `<bridge>` will produce the result into the `replyChannel` from a different Thread.

Your 3rd party service should be called from that `<service-activator>`, who is the second subscriber to the same `<publish-subscribe-channel>`.